# Unable to get fonts working with @font-face

Tags: css

I'm using google webfonts helper to generate the css for my fonts and then download the font files:  https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com

I generated the following:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Lato';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'),
      url('../Content/fonts/lato-v11-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
   url('../Content/fonts/lato-v11-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'); /*   Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
```

My font files are stored in ~/Content/fonts

I referenced the font like so:

```
body {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 90px;
font-weight: 500;
```

}

However, it seems like no matter what I do, I can't get the font's working.  I checked the computed font family in chrome and it's set to Lato.  It also won't work in any other browser either.

Comment: Where is your CSS file located? Also in Chrome web dev tools, open the `Network` tab and refresh your page. See if your font files loaded or check for file errors.

Comment: use chrome inspect element in consul part it shows error ,check maybe your file doesn't load corectly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your URL is correct.

`url('../Content/fonts/lato-v11-latin-regular.woff2')`

This means that from wherever your CSS file is located, go *back* one directory, then go to the foler `Content/fonts`, but if your fonts are stored at `~/Content/fonts` and your CSS is stored in two sub folders e.g. `/~/assets/css/mycssFile.css` for example your url won't work.

You might try `url('/Content/fonts/lato-v11-latin-regular.woff2')` which will use the root directory of your website, or even better you can try:
`url('/../Content/fonts/lato-v11-latin-regular.woff2')` which will tell go to the root directory, *and* try and go back one folder further which should guarantee you get the root directory. If neither of these fixes your problem, then the issue isn't with the URL, but something else.